# bluehost shared ssl redirect with htaccess

Tags: ruby-on-rails, .htaccess, ssl, bluehost

I am wanting to add a redirect to my bluehost shared ssl page:
https://secure.bluehost.com/~user/page_to_redirect

to here:
http://mydomain.com/folder/new_page

I need this setup, as I am using a website's API, which requires that the callback url is ssl. And i need this redirected to my ruby on rails app.

i have configured my .htacccess (root) like so:

```
    Options -Indexes
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mydomain.\.com$
    RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/mydomain\.com\/" [R=301,L]

    Redirect /page_to_redirect http://mydomain.com/folder/new_page
```

the redirect works for the non ssl page:
mydomain.com/page_to_redirect
but not the ssl page:
https://secure.bluehost.com/~user/page_to_redirect

I just get a 404 error.

does anyone have any experience with this?
Bluehost support was not very helpful at all.

this is what worked:

```
    Options -Indexes
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mydomain.\.com$
    RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/mydomain\.com\/" [R=301,L]

    Redirect 301 /~mydomain/page_to_redirect http://mydomain.com/folder/new_page
```

Comment: Drop bluehost, they suck.

Comment: this is what worked for me, in my htaccess file:  >>>>> Redirect 301 /~mydomain/page_to_redirect http://mydomain.com/folder/new_page

Comment: Feel free to submit that as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what worked:

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mydomain.\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/mydomain\.com\/" [R=301,L]

Redirect 301 /~mydomain/page_to_redirect http://mydomain.com/folder/new_page
```